# How do I start a new line after a period, question mark, and exclamation point?

Tags: java, io

I am writing a program to change an input file. It should start a new line after a ? . and ! but I can't seem to figure it out. Each new line should also begin with an Uppercase letter which I think I got. It should also eliminate unnecessary spaces which I also believe I got.

For example: hello?    bartender. can I have      a drink!whiskey please.

```
Output should be: 
Hello? 
Bartender. 
Can I have a drink!whiskey please.
```

It should only make a new line after those operators followed by a whitespace. If there is no space it will not make new line.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class TextFileProcessorDemo
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String fileName, answer;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Test Input File:");
    fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
    File file = new File(fileName);

    PrintWriter outputStream = null;

    try
    {
        outputStream = new PrintWriter(file);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error opening file" + file);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println("Enter a line of text:");
    String line = keyboard.nextLine();
    outputStream.println(line);
    outputStream.close();
    System.out.println("This line was written to:" + " " + file);
    System.out.println(" ");

    TextFileProcessor.textFile();


}

}
```

Second Class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TextFileProcessor
{
public static void textFile()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Test Input File:");
    String inputFile = keyboard.next();
    System.out.print("Output File:");
    String outputFile = keyboard.next();

    try
    {
        BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
        String line = inputStream.readLine();

        line = line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
        line = line.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + line.substring(1);
        //This is where I would like to add code

        while(line != null)
        {
            outputStream.println(line);
            System.out.println(line);
            line = inputStream.readLine();
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File" + inputFile + " not found");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error reading from file" + inputFile);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple regex would suffice:

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        for(String s:"hello? bartender. can I have a drink!whiskey please.".replaceAll("(\\W)(\\s+)", "$1\n").split("\n"))
            System.out.println(s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()+s.substring(1));
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Hello?
Bartender.
Can I have a drink!whiskey please.
```

https://ideone.com/Zo2N7Q

Comment: It worked! Thank You so much! The only problem I have now is that the new lines don't begin with an Uppercase letter. I thought I fixed that. Any ideas?

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I can't get the loop to work on my code though. I'm not sure why. I get many errors

Comment: @nedst3r what errors do you get? .. have you copied the code as it is?

Answer (score 0):

Would this solve your problem?

```
if(line.endsWith("! ") || line.endsWith("? ") || line.endsWith(". ")) {
  line = line + '\n';
}
```

Comment: Would it solve the problem? Since the characters are not always at the end of the line this would not achieve the result the OP is looking for.

Comment: It didn't work...but thank you for the response. I didn't even think of something like that

Comment: `line = line.replace("? ", "?\n").replace("! ", "!\n").replace(". ", ".\n");` This version would insert newlines anywhere in your line.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help. I find this easy to understand!

Comment: Would you know how to capitalize the first letter on each new line? I tried using a for loop but no luck

Comment: @nedst3r I have created following gist for you: https://gist.github.com/wowselim/9a507c97e8b5a2c84bac34317c342043

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "capture group" in a regex to achieve what you want.

```
line.replaceAll("(\\? )|(\\! )|(\\. )", "$0\n");
```

**Update:**

With regards to your comment on how to capitalize the first character of each line, you can use the `toUpperCase` method in the `Character` class.

```
line = Character.toUpperCase(line.charAt(0)) + line.substring(1);
```

**Note:**

If you are using Java 1.7 or above you should consider using a try-with-resources block for the `Scanner`

```
try (Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)) {
   ...
}
```

Then when you read input from the user you can manipulate it to the correct format before writing to your file. For example you could do something like...

```
 System.out.println("Enter a line of text:");
 String[] lines = keyboard.nextLine().replaceAll("(\\? )|(\\! )|(\\. )", "$0\n").split("\n");

  // Replace the first character of each line with an uppercase character
  for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        lines[i] = Character.toUpperCase(lines[i].charAt(0)) + lines[i].substring(1);
  }

  Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
  Files.write(path, Arrays.asList(lines), Charset.defaultCharset());

  System.out.println("This line was written to:" + " " + path.toString());
  System.out.println(" ");
```

As for reading and writing from files you are better off using the non-blocking `Files` class in the `java.nio` package. It's as simple as the following;

```
Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
Files.write(path, Arrays.asList(lines), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Then for reading your file you can just use the `readAllLines` method.

```
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);

    for (String line : lines ) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```